Inexpensive and quick hematology tests
I was interested in measuring hemoglobin, hematocrit, erythrocyte sedimentation rate, and dna damage, but most methods require expensive equipment or take to long to perform.
I though about using 4ml EDTA tubes, draw the sample, then put it on a stable surface at a constant temperature after shaking it, wait for a period of time, maybe 40 minutes, and check the separation of plasma and RBC with a caliper to estimate ESR roughly. After that put it in a electric centrifuge, and after separation see the volume of RBC to plasma again with a caliper to estimate the hematocrit. Lastly shine a light from the bottom of the tube in a regular lighting environment and measure the color (which i suppose would mean higher red) through a digital camera, of the RBC aggregate to estimate the hemoglobin content.
For estimating dna damage I only know about the comet assay, but i feel is too expensive and very time consuming to perform, so any ideas would be appreciated.
I know these measures aren't standard or precise, but what Im interested in is if they are actually measuring what they are supposed to be measuring and are sensible enough to some level of variability.
I also want suggestions regarding the DNA damage measures, a very rough estimate is fine.

Is the intent here to satisfy your curiosity, or are you a health care provider in a location lacking proper equipment? If you want to test yourself for fun, go for it. Afterwards, compare to lab results to see how well you did. You might be surprised at how different your results are. (There's a reason labs do these tests.) "I also want suggestions regarding the DNA damage measures, a very rough estimate is fine." That's not possible (by any stretch of the imagination.)
